# Lotus Notes views Folder. Number of unread emails

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm using lotus notes views. This is unfortunately not showing the number of emails or Unread emails. Is there a work around for this?
Thank you!
Snorge

Answer (score 0):

The non-programming answer* is that in any view, you can click on the Edit menu and Select All (or just press Ctrl-A) to select all documents. The number of selected documents will be displayed on the status bar at the bottom of the window.

To get the number of unread documents in the view, first click on the View Menu, then Show, then Unread Only, and then use the same procedure as above (Edit - Select All, or Ctrl-A) and the number of unread documents will be displayed on the status bar.

*Notes programmers can design an application that includes an embedded outline that shows the number of unread documents in each view. Current versions of Notes have this feature in the mail template, so users can see unread counts for the various views and folders in their mailboxes.